# How to add new column to an dataframe (to the front not end)?

Tags: r, dataframe

How to add a new variable to an existing data frame, but I want to add to the front not end.
eg. my dataframe is

```
b c d
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

I want to add a new variable a, so the dataframe will looks like

```
a b c d
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
```

Comment: `cbind(a = 0, df)` should do it.

Answer (score 136):

Use `cbind` e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(b = runif(6), c = rnorm(6))
cbind(a = 0, df)
```

giving:

```
> cbind(a = 0, df)
  a         b          c
1 0 0.5437436 -0.1374967
2 0 0.5634469 -1.0777253
3 0 0.9018029 -0.8749269
4 0 0.1649184 -0.4720979
5 0 0.6992595  0.6219001
6 0 0.6907937 -1.7416569
```

Answer (score 29):

```
df <- data.frame(b = c(1, 1, 1), c = c(2, 2, 2), d = c(3, 3, 3))
df
##   b c d
## 1 1 2 3
## 2 1 2 3
## 3 1 2 3

df <- data.frame(a = c(0, 0, 0), df)
df
##   a b c d
## 1 0 1 2 3
## 2 0 1 2 3
## 3 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: I think this is better than cbind.

Comment: `data.frame(a = 0, df)` suffices.

Answer (score 14):

> Add column "a"

```
> df["a"] <- 0
> df
  b c d a
1 1 2 3 0
2 1 2 3 0
3 1 2 3 0
```

> Sort by column using colum name

```
> df <- df[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
> df
  a b c d
1 0 1 2 3
2 0 1 2 3
3 0 1 2 3
```

> Or sort by column using index

```
> df <- df[colnames(df)[c(4,1:3)]]
> df
  a b c d
1 0 1 2 3
2 0 1 2 3
3 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: For the second step: `df[c("a", setdiff(names(df), "a"))]` is more generalisable.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do it in a `tidyverse` manner, try `add_column` from `tibble`, which allows you to specifiy where to place the new column with `.before` or `.after` parameter:

```
library(tibble)

df <- data.frame(b = c(1, 1, 1), c = c(2, 2, 2), d = c(3, 3, 3))
add_column(df, a = 0, .before = 1)

#   a b c d
# 1 0 1 2 3
# 2 0 1 2 3
# 3 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 6):

The previous answers show 3 approaches

1. By creating a new data frame
2. By using "cbind"
3. By adding column "a", and sort data frame by columns using column names or indexes

Let me show #4 approach "By using "cbind" and "rename" that works for my case

1. Create data frame

   ```
   df <- data.frame(b = c(1, 1, 1), c = c(2, 2, 2), d = c(3, 3, 3))
   ```
2. Get values for "new" column

   ```
   new_column <- c(0, 0, 0)
   ```
3. Combine "new" column with existed

   ```
   df <- cbind(new_column, df)
   ```
4. Rename "new" column name

   ```
   colnames(df)[1] <- "a"
   ```

Comment: why would you just add steps to the previous answer XD ... no need for another var in your env or renaming if you pass the column assignment with the desired name as an argument `df <- cbind(a = 0), df)`

Answer (score 3):

cbind inherents order by its argument order.

User your first column(s) as your **first argument**

cbind(fst_col , df)

```
  fst_col   df_col1   df_col2
1 0             0.2      -0.1
2 0             0.2      -0.1
3 0             0.2      -0.1
4 0             0.2      -0.1
5 0             0.2      -0.1
```

cbind(df, last_col)

```
  df_col1   df_col2  last_col
1 0.2      -0.1             0
2 0.2      -0.1             0
3 0.2      -0.1             0
4 0.2      -0.1             0
5 0.2      -0.1             0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the name `a` dynamic, you can just `df["a"] <- 0`, or :

```r
colname = "a"
`[<-` (df, colname, value = 0)
```

---

One use case:

```r
`%flat.by%` = function (xss, flatter = c) xss %>% Reduce (\(a,b) flatter (a,b) , x = .) ;

`%rbind.withname%` = 
function (namedlist.df, namefield.name = "group.from") 
  namedlist.df %>% 
  {Map (df = ., group.from = names(.)
        , \ (df, group.from) `[<-` (df, namefield.name, value = group.from)
  )} %flat.by% rbind

#' Use like: 
#' `named_df_list %rbind.withname% "from"`
#' 
#' Then you can get a df with a new col,
#'  and that col 's value is the
#'  data frame element's name at the `named_df_list`.
#'
```